# The order of the center of a finite group divides the group order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**PROPERTY**
Let $G$ be an finite group. Then for every group $P\subset G$ the order of $P$ must be a multiple of the order of $G$.

Does the same property hold for the center of the group? I mean, is the order of $Z(G)$ a multiple of the order of $G$?

Where $Z(G)$ is the set of element that commute with all other element of the group.

Comment: You're stating it wrongly. The theorem is "The order of $G$ is divisible by the order of any subgroup of $G$".

Comment: To elaborate on Peter's comment, let $G$ be any group. If $e\in G$ is the identity, certainly $\{e\}\subseteq G$ is a subgroup, but $\left|\{e\}\right| = 1$ is not a multiple of $\left|G\right|$ unless $\left|G\right| = 1$ (if $G$ has more than two elements, then $\left|G\right| > \left|\{e\}\right| = 1$, so $1$ can't be an integer multiple of $\left|G\right|$).

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Thanks for pointing this out, maybe a language problem. I took the liberty to modify the question to something more meaningful.

Comment: @azimut Oh, but please wait untill the OP sees his/her mistake! Else it might go unnoticed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Because of $x1 = 1x$ for all $x\in G$, $1\in Z(G)$.
- Assume $g\in Z(G)$ and let $x\in G$. Then
  $$g^{-1}x = xg^{-1} \iff g(g^{-1}x) = g(xg^{-1}).$$
  This is true, since the left hand side is $g(g^{-1}x) = (gg^{-1})x = 1x = x$ and the right hand side is $g(xg^{-1}) = (gx)g^{-1} = (xg)g^{-1} = x(gg^{-1}) = x1 = x$.
  So $g^{-1} \in Z(G)$.
- Let $g,h\in Z(G)$ and $x\in G$. Then by the group axioms and the center property $$(gh)x = g(hx) = g(xh) = (gx)h = (xg)h = x(gh).$$
  So $gh\in Z(G)$

Together, we have shown that $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$ and therefore, $\lvert Z(G)\rvert $ divides $\lvert G\rvert$.

Comment: The OP has written a wrong statement above. Did you realize?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Maybe a language problem confusing 'divisible' with 'divides'.

Comment: It seems so. =/

Comment: @azimut Is $C(a)$ (centralizer of a $\in G$ ) is also an subgroup.

Comment: @stranger001: Yes, just check it in a similar way as above.

Answer (score 2):

Just prove the center is a group, and you get the result.

Comment: you mean I have to prove center is subgroup

Comment: Any Hints how to prove that??,Don't tell me answer.

Comment: @stranger001, Show 1 is in the center. Let a,b be in the center and show ab is in the center and show that a^{-1} is in the center.

Comment: The OP seems to mean the otherwise. He says "order of $G$ is divisible by order of $Z_G$", meaning wether $$|G|\;\mid\; |Z_G|$$

is true or not. I pointed it out in the comments above.

Comment: @caveman Please check my solution

$property\ 1:$$e$ commutes to every element $\therefore$ e must be in $Z(G)$.

$property\ 2:$suppose $a,b \in G$ $\therefore ax=xa \implies ex=a^{-1}xa \implies xa^{-1}=a^{-1}x$. That means $a^{-1} \in Z(G)$

$property\ 3:$Given that $a \in Z(G)$ $\therefore ax=xa \implies bax=xab \implies (ab)x=x(ab) \therefore \ ab $ commutes to every element of $G$, $ab$ must be in $Z(G)$.

Comment: @stranger001, yes perfect

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make sure you know the following terminology:

We say that an integer $m$ **divides** an integer $n$ whenever $\ell=mk$ for some integer $k$, that is $\dfrac \ell m$ is an integer.

We say that an integer $m$ **is divisible by** $n$ whenever $m=\ell k$ for some integer $k$, that is $\dfrac m\ell $ is an integer.

Thus, saying $m$ **divides** $\ell $ is the same as saying $\ell$ is **divisible by** $m$.

Thus, the theorem should read:

> **THEOREM** Let $H\leq G$. Then $|H|$ divides $|G|$, or $|G|$ is divisible by $|H|$. In particular >$$|G|=|G:H||H|$$